# javascript ignoring jsp code

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp

I'm having the following problem on this code:

```
<center><button onclick="agregartabla_materias()">Agregar nueva tabla</button></center>
<script>
    function agregartabla_materias() {
    <%
            String sql = "create table if not exists materias ("
                    + "codigo decimal (8),"
                    + "nombre varchar (40),"
                    + "turno text [],"
                    + "ref_profesor varchar (10)"
                    + ");";
            Statement myStmt = con.getConexion().createStatement();
            myStmt.executeUpdate(sql);
    %>
    }
</script>
```

I want a button that, when clicked, it should send the sql query to the database. When i open the page, the query is already sent, without clicking the button. To test some things, i deleted the table on the database and tried to click the button, it didn't create the table. So it's like the javascript code is empty and the <% %> is outside of it so it's always called when i reload the page and not when i click the button.

Thanks in advice.

Comment: that wont work on front end. you need to have a backend command that and attach it to the button

Comment: I don't even know what front end is :D my teacher told me to create a website with buttons that when clicked, create the tables, insert data, create foreign and primary keys, etc

Comment: read some more then before doing your homework :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scriptlet is executed when the JSP is compiled - that's why the code is executed on each reload.

The javascript doesn't include it because the code is executed and doesn't print anything and the method remains empty.

Using scriptlets is not good approach but if you want to do it like that you can create another jsp that executes that and call it with javascript (or with ajax). This is the front end - call to back end - return result to fron end. Javascript is the front end (executed with the client) and the code you want to execute is the back end (executed on the server). The client (browser) cannot connect to your database and execute sqls, it can just send request to the back end and the back end should do the work.

Try with two jsp pages.

button.jsp:

```
<center><a href="executeSql.jsp">Agregar nueva tabla</a></center>
```

executeSql.jsp:

```
<script>
    <%
        String sql = "create table if not exists materias ("
                + "codigo decimal (8),"
                + "nombre varchar (40),"
                + "turno text [],"
                + "ref_profesor varchar (10)"
                + ");";
        Statement myStmt = con.getConexion().createStatement();
        myStmt.executeUpdate(sql);
%>
window.location="button.jsp";
```

This is a very bad example but can work. This way the first jsp (button.jsp) when clicked will call the second jsp. The back-end code will execute and it will redirect back to the button.jsp

Comment: Thanks Veselin. I changed the code like this, but it doesnt work, must be wrong :D  well i can't add code here

Comment: You cannot do it with so simple code. You need javascript in a webpage to call the server (jsp page) and the server to do something. In your example you can do it with two JSP pages

Comment: onclick="agregartabla_materias.jsp" is wrong isn't it? then i created another jsp file called like that and the code of the OP surrounded by <% %>

Comment: onclick is bad yeah. First onclick written like that will not do anything. It should be javascript function. And second it will not work anyway ;) I tried to write a simple solution in the response. I am not sure it will work because I haven't tested it but you can get the idea.

Comment: Thank you so much for that code, that kinda worked out. It just doesnt redirect me back to button.jsp (the original page) but it succesfully created the table

Comment: well I made a mistake there. it shouldn't be window.location.href but window.location=.... I am writing without testing so you need to do some work by yourself

Comment: That doesn't work either :D I did some research and i think window.location.assign is what i need

Comment: Here you go! Thank you very much for your support

Answer (score -1):

**< button onclick = "agregartabla_materias();">**

try it this way. and do specify which page language are you using.

hope it might be helpful

Comment: Thanks for your time! Same problems, code is called when the page is loaded and clicking the button doesnt create the table :(

Comment: which page development language are you using? 

try making the code using scriptlet in main body and just executing the query in the function area of the code. **<%= %>**

Comment: Thanks again, i'm using HTML